# Heroku node S3 Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm having an issue when following this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node

I've setup the code here https://desolate-island-40106.herokuapp.com/account and get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/nns.app.images/Nom%20Nom%20Snap.png?AWSAccessKeyId…=1466571088&Signature=9zyWWJrY5oQQtunDbZ1oRtVrJSo%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://desolate-island-40106.herokuapp.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

The app gets a signed request successfully but the error occurs in the below where xhr.status = 0:

```
function uploadFile(file, signedRequest, url){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', signedRequest);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        document.getElementById('preview').src = url;
        document.getElementById('avatar-url').value = url;
      }
      else{
        alert('Could not upload file.');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(file);
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, have you cleared your browser cache and/or tested with a different browser?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did try that but with no luck